# Client side router's version of window.onload?

Tags: javascript, angular, reactjs, dom, react-router

I'm having some difficulties finding ways to tell when every resource (e.g., images, videos, etc) has been loaded. I can easily do it on the first page by using `window.onload`, but the `load` event doesn't seem to fire when changing routes via a client side router. I'm specifically using react-router, if that helps.

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

To change `window` dynamically, do this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

class YourComponent extends Component {

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) { 
    if (this.props.location !== prevProps.location) { // detect page change
      window.scrollTo(0, 0); // for example // or document.querySelector ... or any js
    }
  }

  render() {
   return this.props.children
  }

}

export default withRouter(YourComponent)
```

Then wrap as a parent component :

```
// import react and everything
// import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

// in your render 
<Router> 
  <YourComponent>
    <OtherComponentOrRouting />
  </YourComponent>
<Router>
```